# My neural network only predicts one thing

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, data-science

I am trying to implement it on python from scratch. I tried a lot but couldn't find the bug in my implementation. Whenever I use my 'predict' function it always outputs, 0.

I have also tested each and every function that you'll see in my code below using random arrays of the same shape as x and y and all of them seems to work perfectly. I also have previously cleaned the data.

```
import os
os.chdir(r'path where my data is store')#This block of code changes directory to where my data set
```

Creating a dataframe and assigning values to the input and target vector

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('clean_data.csv')
X = df[['radius_mean', 'texture_mean', 'perimeter_mean',
   'area_mean', 'smoothness_mean', 'compactness_mean', 'concavity_mean',
   'concave points_mean', 'symmetry_mean', 'fractal_dimension_mean',
   'radius_se', 'texture_se', 'perimeter_se', 'area_se', 'smoothness_se',
   'compactness_se', 'concavity_se', 'concave points_se', 'symmetry_se',
   'fractal_dimension_se', 'radius_worst', 'texture_worst',
   'perimeter_worst', 'area_worst', 'smoothness_worst',
   'compactness_worst', 'concavity_worst', 'concave points_worst',
   'symmetry_worst', 'fractal_dimension_worst']].values
Y = df['diagnosis'].values 
Y = Y.reshape(569,1)
```

Splitting the data in training and testing data(x and y are training set and xt and yt are test set)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x, xt, y, yt = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 40)
x, xt, y, yt = x.T, xt.T, y.T, yt.T
```

initializing parameters

```
def iniparams(layer_dims):
params = {}
for l in range(1,len(layer_dims)):
    params['W' + str(l)] = np.random.randn(layer_dims[l],layer_dims[l - 1])*0.01
    params['b' + str(l)] = np.zeros((layer_dims[l],1))
return params
```

Writing helper functions #1

```
def sigmoid(Z):
return 1/(1 + np.exp(-Z)), Z
```

#2

```
def relu(Z):
return np.maximum(0, Z), Z
```

Linear forward

```
def linearfwd(W, A, b):
Z = np.dot(W, A) + b
linear_cache = (W, A, b)
return Z, linear_cache
```

Forward activation

```
def fwdactivation(W, A_prev, b, activation):
if activation == 'sigmoid':
    Z, linear_cache = linearfwd(W, A_prev, b)
    A, activation_cache = sigmoid(Z)
elif activation == 'relu':
    Z, linear_cache = linearfwd(W, A_prev, b)
    A, activation_cache = relu(Z)
cache = (linear_cache, activation_cache)
return A, cache
```

Forward model

```
def fwdmodel(x, params):
caches = []
L = len(params)//2
A = x
for l in range(1, L):
    A_prev = A
    A, cache = fwdactivation(params['W' + str(l)], A_prev, params['b' + str(l)], 'relu')
    caches.append(cache)
AL, cache = fwdactivation(params['W' + str(L)], A, params['b' + str(L)], 'sigmoid')
caches.append(cache)
return AL, caches
```

Computing cost

```
def J(AL, y):
return -np.sum(np.multiply(np.log(AL), y) + np.multiply(np.log(1 - AL), (1 - y)))/y.shape[1]
```

backward sigmoid

```
def sigmoidbkwd(dA, cache):
Z = cache
s = 1/(1 + np.exp(-Z))
dZ = dA*s*(1 - s)
return dZ
```

backward relu`

```
def sigmoidbkwd(dA, cache):
Z = cache
s = 1/(1 + np.exp(-Z))
dZ = dA*s*(1 - s)
return dZ
```

linear bkwd

```
def linearbkwd(dZ, cache):
W, A_prev, b = cache
m = A_prev.shape[1]
dW = np.dot(dZ, A_prev.T)/m
db = np.sum(dZ, axis = 1, keepdims = True)/m
dA_prev = np.dot(W.T, dZ)
return dW, dA_prev, db
```

backward activation

```
def bkwdactivation(dA, cache, activation):
linear_cache, activation_cache = cache
if activation == 'sigmoid':
    dZ = sigmoidbkwd(dA, activation_cache)
    dW, dA_prev, db = linearbkwd(dZ, linear_cache)
if activation == 'relu':
    dZ = relubkwd(dA, activation_cache)
    dW, dA_prev, db = linearbkwd(dZ, linear_cache)
return dW, dA_prev, db
```

backward model

```
def bkwdmodel(AL, y, cache):
grads = {}
L = len(cache)
dAL = -(np.divide(y, AL) - np.divide(1 - y,1 - AL))
current_cache = cache[L - 1]
grads['dW' + str(L)], grads['dA' + str(L - 1)], grads['db' + str(L)] = bkwdactivation(dAL, current_cache, 'sigmoid')
for l in reversed(range(L - 1)):
    current_cache = cache[l]
    dW_temp, dA_prev_temp, db_temp = bkwdactivation(grads['dA' + str(l + 1)], current_cache, 'relu')
    grads['dW' + str(l + 1)] = dW_temp
    grads['dA' + str(l)] = dA_prev_temp
    grads['db' + str(l + 1)] = db_temp
return grads
```

Optimizing parameters using gradient descent

```
def optimize(grads, params, alpha):
L = len(params)//2
for l in range(1, L + 1):
    params['W' + str(l)] = params['W' + str(l)] - alpha*grads['dW' + str(l)]
    params['b' + str(l)] = params['b' + str(l)] - alpha*grads['db' + str(l)]
return params
```

Neural Network Model

```
def model(x, y, layer_dims, iters):
costs = []
params = iniparams(layer_dims)
for i in range(1, iters):
    AL, caches = fwdmodel(x, params)
    cost = J(AL, y)
    costs.append(cost)
    grads = bkwdmodel(AL, y, caches)
    params = optimize(grads, params, 1.2)
    if i%100 == 0:
        print('Cost after', i,'iterations is:', cost)
        costs.append(cost)
return costs, params
```

calculation (The cost does gets mitigated [Cost Vs Iterations(Y,X) curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbEcG.png))

```
costs, params = model(x, y, [30,8,5,4,4,3,1], 3000)
```

Prediction function

```
def predict(x,params):

AL, cache = fwdmodel(x,params)
predictions = AL >= 0.5

return predictions
```

And finally when I do this

```
predictions = predict(xt,params)
predictions
```

I get this:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

What am I doing wrong?

[here's the link to the dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data)

Answer (score 0):

I don't'see why you've transposed your train-test-split output. Why use xt.T, x.T anyway?
You should try printing your params(array) output and xt(array) output and see how they are.
Are they similar? Does your params output give the right result? Check all of that.

Comment: Hello Harshini, I didn't understand what you meant by params output and xt output. And what is meant by 'right' result? Also, I transposed my input and output to arrange them columns-wise, which means that 1 columns instead of representing features would represent an entire training example, therefore in this case I'll have around 31 features and 400 training examples. Or, 31 rows and 400 columns. (Also, is this something that needs to be done or can I work it out without transposing?)

Comment: I think I found a potential solution to my problem. The reason why my model was predicting only one class was because the value of 'AL' was very very small. So, I found out two potential solution to my problem : 1) Scaling AL so that it's values lie between 0 and 1 or 2)changing the threshold to the mean of AL (the solution that I used since using np.mean(AL) is easier :P) Thank you Harshini for taking your time to help me out :D